# Window Authentication in Linux .net core

Tags: linux, windows, asp.net-core, authentication, kerberos

I'm trying to make work window authentication in Linux/Debian server with Kerberos. I'm using .net core 3.1 and IdentityServer4. For now I had joined Linux to the Windows AD like docs say:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel-1

I have managet to work kerberos from bash with -kinit command. I also made work Apache2 with kerberos.

But in .net core it's always returns in logs
[17:39:53 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler  AuthenticationScheme: Negotiate was challenged.

[17:39:54 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler None

if I set in krb5.conf wrong encript type I have error like:

Interop+NetSecurityNative+GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information(Request ticket server **** kvno 4 enctype aes256-cts found in keytab but cannot decrypt ticket).
at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.GssAcceptSecurityContext(SafeGssContextHandle& context, Byte[] buffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, UInt32& outFlags)
at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.AcceptSecurityContext(SafeFreeCredentials credentialsHandle, SafeDeleteContext& securityContext, ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags, Byte[] incomingBlob, ChannelBinding channelBinding, Byte[]& resultBlob, ContextFlagsPal& contextFlags)

So the token is passing GSSAPI in normal mode and trying to validate user, but there is alwayse None in anwser. Can somebody help me get what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: as I mentued, I'm getting "None" from that statuses I guess.
```if (errorCode == SecurityStatusPalErrorCode.OK || errorCode == SecurityStatusPalErrorCode.ContinueNeeded || errorCode == SecurityStatusPalErrorCode.CompleteNeeded) { status = BlobErrorType.None; }```
So, my request can't pass some steps in ```private byte[] GetOutgoingBlob(byte[] incomingBlob, out BlobErrorType status, out Exception error)``` method.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c14360e98770d030dae5c32994e0750a1850e6b8/src/Security/Authentication/Negotiate/src/Internal/ReflectedNegotiateState.cs#L78

Answer (score 0):

I got it by using `[Authorize]` attribute instead of `HttpContext.ChallengeAsync()`.