# How to configure windows authentication in linux/ubuntu for dotnet core (.NET 6)

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, .net-6.0, windows-authentication

I tried the published file in windows environment with IIS, Apache and Nginx as reverse proxy.
All work without any issue except in linux ubuntu 20.04.
It gives below error:

```
  Content root path: xxxxxxxxx fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[5]
  An exception occurred while processing the authentication request.
  Interop+NetSecurityNative+GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Keytab FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab is nonexistent or empty).
```

I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70881607/window-authentication-in-linux-net-core) no solutions at all.
Followed Microsoft docs [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel).
Have anyone tried hosting .Net 6.0 in linux with windows authentication?
It works without windows authentication but I need it with windows authentication as it is a migrated .net 4.6 code.
Any help and directions will be great.

Note. New to linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience here, but this is the relevant part of the error message that you should be searching Google for:

```
Keytab FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab is nonexistent or empty
```

I found [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/731617/163227) that looks promising. It suggests that running this will create the keytab file, and *might* fix the error message:

```
net ads keytab create -U administrator
```